# Hilbert's construction of multiplication of two numbers

Tags: geometry, math-history

I am now reading Hilbert's "Foundations of Geometry", section 15, where he describes there a geometric way to construct, given two segments of length $a$ and $b$, a segment of length $ab$ (in short: let $L$ be the line connecting the points $(1,0)$ and $(0,a)$. Let $T$ be the line parallel to $L$ and going through $(b,0)$. Then $T$ intersects the $y$-axis at the point $(0,ab)$).

was this construction known to the greeks? or to other cultures that dealt with geometry before the greeks, e.g. the babylonians?

thank you very much,

David

Answer (score 3):

The result can be thought of as done in Proposition 12, Book VI, of *Elements*.

For the proposition, I suggest going to [this link](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookVI/propVI12.html).  There you will find a brief discussion of Descartes' interpretation. For more detail on the proposition, please see Heath's heavily annotated *Elements*.

Comment: Thanks! and what other cultures that were geometrically-oriented, line the babylonian mathematics? did they know this construction?

Comment: I do not know, and do not think of  Babylonian mathematical culture as having a geometric orientation. Certainly not in the Greek sense.  The "geometric" work described in detail in Hoyrup's book has a basically computational character.

Comment: But please, note that for the Greeks the *product* of two segments was a square (and of three a cube) while Descartes free himself from this "restricted" interpretation: for him, the product of $n$ segments is again a segment, with $n$ whatever, while in Euclid's we cannot find the product of more than three segments.

Comment: great, thanks for everyone!

Answer (score 2):

The Greeks had no coordinate systems, and they thought in terms of ratios and/or areas rather than in terms of products of numbers. With that proviso, then yes, this construction was known to the Greeks, and I'm almost sure it is in Euclid but I do not know Euclid well enough to give a citation.

I think the statement in Euclid would be close to something like this. Given three line segments $A,B$, and given another line segment $C$, one can construct a line segment $D$ such that the ratio of (the lengths of) $A$ to $C$ equals the ratio of $B$ to $D$.